# Strain gauges' readings at 1 kHz

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, signal-processing, strain-gage

**I want to connect 8 strain gauges to an aluminum scooter frame and capture readings at 1 kHz**. The strain gauges are Full bridge 350 ohms with a very small output voltage (in the range of mV). I have found a "HAT" that will convert the analog signals to digital as input for Rasberry Pi but it needs signal conditioning first. (https://www.mccdaq.com/DAQ-HAT/MCC-128.aspx).

It would need me to bump up the voltage to a readable value to work (say 0 - 5 volts) and also a bridge completion module (if necessary).

How can I go about this? The ultimate goal is to read the strain gauge readings and any solution that directly tackles the problem will be very helpful, too.

Comment: The strain gauge AFE and ADC is quite demanding, specially for such speed. You'd better find some ready made quality boards,  for example AD7190, China is your friend, but not all, just expensive stuff. https://it.aliexpress.com/item/4000089115185.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.51db22b5PvCCiV&algo_pvid=ab232180-ec7e-44c6-a065-4c3138306073&algo_exp_id=ab232180-ec7e-44c6-a065-4c3138306073-51

Comment: You need to determine how to minimize noise voltage to achieve a specified S/N ratio and thus minimum gain with Vout/ resolution * full scale * N channels to meet sampling rate of Mux. either high gain and low resolution per bit near sensor

Comment: A strain gage indeed is a bridge of resistances, with typically two variable.  There's no output voltage until you provide an excitation voltage or current.  Don't forget about the excitation part of the circuit!

Comment: Are you binding strain gauges directly to the frame? That's a more difficult problem than the DAQ solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want amplifiers, take Instrumentation OPamp such AD622.
Sample/hold components (LF398) would be helpfull, but not really needed.
You can then use a microcontroller who ADC speed is fast enough. I think a STM32F1.. (BluePill) is ok. Raspberry too. Some 16/24bits ADC boards can also be used if they are correctly interfaced.

Example : AD7606 (16 €) ; 16 bits, simultaneous sampling ; on Arduino Uno
// Speed = 178us for reading serially 8 channels -> 5300 sps on 8 channels, no printing. Can be upgraded (parallel configuration) in speed by software.

Or ... ADS1256 (16 €) 24-Bit, not simultneous sampling, 30ksps, 8-Ch Delta-Sigma ADC With PGA for Factory Automation and Process Control. Not tested.